# SOQL on OpportunityContactRole in Trigger doesn't return any result in Lightning

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, opportunitycontactrole

I have a trigger on `Opportunity` object, which populates primary campaign source using a custom logic.

As part of my logic, I am querying `OpportunityContactRole` in the trigger. The query gives result and the logic works fine in classic view.

But the same Trigger and query doesn't work when I create opportunity in lightning view.

Below is an excerpt from my code:

```
for (Opportunity oppObj : newOppList) {
    oppSet.add(oppObj.Id); //for campaign source
}

System.debug('oppSet::'+oppSet); //Debug has values

/*********for populating campaign source************/
Map<Id,Id> oppPrimaryContactMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
for(OpportunityContactRole oppContactRole: [select ContactID, OpportunityId, isPrimary from OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppSet AND isPrimary = true]){
    oppPrimaryContactMap.put(oppContactRole.OpportunityId,oppContactRole.ContactID);
}
System.debug('oppPrimaryContactMap::'+oppPrimaryContactMap); //This is blank in Lightning, but has values in classic view

Map<Id, Id> contactCampaingMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
for(CampaignMember cmObj: [SELECT Id,CampaignId,Campaign.Name,Campaign.StartDate,ContactId,Contact.Name FROM CampaignMember WHERE ContactId IN :oppPrimaryContactMap.values() AND CampaignMember.CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:365 ORDER BY CampaignMember.CreatedDate]){
    System.debug('cmObj::'+cmObj);
    if(!contactCampaingMap.containsKey(cmObj.ContactId))
    contactCampaingMap.put(cmObj.ContactId,cmObj.CampaignId);
}
System.debug('contactCampaingMap::'+contactCampaingMap);
List<Opportunity> oppListToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
for(Opportunity opp: newOppList) {
    Opportunity oppNew = new Opportunity();
    oppNew.Id = opp.Id;
    oppNew.CampaignId = contactCampaingMap.get(oppPrimaryContactMap.get(opp.Id));
    oppListToUpdate.add(oppNew);
}

if(oppListToUpdate.size()>0) {
    update oppListToUpdate;
}
```

> Any insights why the debug 'oppPrimaryContactMap' is blank in
>   lightning but has value in Classic view opportunity creation.

Comment: It shouldn't be the case. Trigger are not related to classic or lightnging.. they are related to events that are fired. The event is triggering from standard page or any lightnng components or vf page.

Comment: Yes I know, this shouldn't be the case. But I have tested it and I have replicated it multiple times

Comment: is it standard page you are creating opportunity or a lighting component?

Comment: Standard Opportunity Creation Page

Comment: I will try to  replicate it. Can u give me some more information like which trigger event is after insert or before insert on Opportunity

Comment: Please explain more about newOppList? And when you are firing the trigger?

Comment: newOppList will have `Trigger.new` values. the code is in handler and it is triggered on after insert

Comment: Your issue could be related to known issue, you may like to reach out to SF support if you are observing this every time. I am aware of at least one [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCRCQA2&title=isclone-and-getclonesourceid-apis-not-working-for-contact-in-lightning) (not related), where things in trigger work in classic and not lightning. Also, I can see a similar issue being reported [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005RpbQAE).

Comment: Yes thanks Jayant, I am reaching out to SF support, will post if I have any updates